# Delete operation finding a relationship that doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

In my multi-tenant site, I have the following database structure:

```
Public (shared):
    tenants
    domains
    users

Test:
    users
    clients
    projects
        projectusers
    tasks

Test2:
    users
    clients
    projects
        projectusers
    tasks
```

This is a simplified list - all three schemas include (among others) auth_permissions, auth_group, and auth_group_permissions.

The projectusers table (cross-ref that ties users to projects), has a One-to-One field for the User table, and a ForeignKey to the projects table, as follows:

```py
class ProjectUser(DateFieldsModelMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=_('User'),
        related_name='user_projects',
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name=_('Project'),
        related_name='project_users',
    )
    ...other fields omitted...
```

The point is, the reference from projectusers to users is defined in the ProjectUser model.  There's no reference from User model back to ProjectUser.

I wrote a load_fixtures (management) command to, well, load fixtures to set up our dev site(s) with the data we'd need to do preliminary testing (before writing/running unit-tests).

One of the things that command does is empty the auth_permissions table, reset the auto-increment value back to 1, and then import its fixture so that all IDs match across local dev sites, and (eventually) in production.  This is necessary because fixtures for auth_group and auth_group_permissions reference permissions by ID.

The error I'm getting occurs during the delete process on that table when running in the "public" schema.  Note there is no projectusers table in Public.  This is the line that does the delete on auth_permissions:

```py
    model.objects.all().delete()
```

That is line 215 in the load_fixtures command, in the clear_table() method.  You can see that line referenced in the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/code/src/virticl_api/utilities/management/commands/load_fixtures.py", line 148, in handle
    self.clear_table(file_path, self.clear_tables[file_name])
  File "/code/src/virticl_api/utilities/management/commands/load_fixtures.py", line 215, in clear_table
    model.objects.all().delete()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 662, in delete
    collector.collect(del_query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 220, in collect
    elif sub_objs:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 272, in __bool__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "projects_projectuser" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ourly_rate", "projects_projectuser"."status" FROM "projects_...
```

So why is that delete method, running in the Public schema, finding a relationship to the projectuser table?

Comment: This is the result of the triggering: Django at least looks what is referring to that model.

Comment: How unfortunate.  Seems like it would (should?) check to see which apps are "active" in shared and tenant settings.

Comment: no, if something is in an installed app that refers to a "dead" app, that model can be seen as "alive". What should it do otherwise?

Comment: Ahh, I see where the issue comes into play.  It's from trying to bridge a multi-tenant setup with the original setup of Django.  In my settings file, there are settings for SHARED_APPS and TENANT_APPS.  That's where I thought it would be easy to see if SHARED_APPS included a projects app (which defines projectusers) and act accordingly.  But the line after those two settings is
```INSTALLED_APPS = list(SHARED_APPS) + [app for app in TENANT_APPS if app not in SHARED_APPS]```
So, bottom line is... Django sees all apps together and can't distinguish between the two types.

Comment: If you'd like to post your comment(s) as an answer, I'll accept it, because you certainly pointed me toward the underlying issue (which answered my question).

Comment: @ExTexan
 How did you fix this ?

Comment: @Subham, To be honest, I can't recall IF we ever fixed that. The structure of our project is so different from what it was at that point in time (almost 3 years ago), so I can't even help you by describing how it is now. It might have been because of reverse relationships (related_name). If that's the case, we solved it by creating models in Public that we knew would always be empty.

Comment: Thanks @ExTexan for responding; I thing we have to do the same or make soft delete.